# RegEx: How to limit a string to be either x characters OR y characters

Tags: regex, string, string-length

Been trying to set a field's behavior limitation to allow users to only enter 11 or 14 digits.
the best I came up so far is to limit the range to be between 11 and 14, but I need it to be either or.

```
^([0-9]{11,14})+$
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Use [or (`|`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^([0-9]{11}|[0-9]{14})$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)** for alternation

```
^([0-9]{11}|[0-9]{14})$
```

The above regex match either 11 or 14 digit string

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the job:

```
^[0-9]{11}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```